# when doing multi-integral, 'takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am doing a multi integral with 4 variables, among them 2 have limits as functions. However the error appears on one of my constant-limit variable. Really cannot figure our why. Many thanks for your advice!

```
from numpy import sqrt, sin, cos, pi, arcsin, maximum
from sympy.functions.special.delta_functions import Heaviside
from scipy.integrate import nquad

def bmax(x):
    return 1.14*10**9/sin(x/2)**(9/7)

def thetal(x,y,z):
    return arcsin(3.7*10**15*sqrt(cos(x/2)**2/10**6-1.23*10**10/z+0.003*sin(x/2)**2*(2.51*10**63/sin(x/2)**9/y**7-1))/(z*sin(x/2)**2*cos(x/2)*(2.51*10**63/sin(x/2)**9/y**7-1)))

def rt(x,y):
    return 3.69*10**12/(2.5*10**63/sin(x/2)**7*y**7-sin(x/2)**2)

def rd(x,y):
    return maximum(1.23*10**10,rt(x,y))

def rl(x,y):
    return rd(x,y)*(sqrt(1+5.04*10**16/(rd(x,y)*cos(x/2)**2))-1)/2

def wbound():
    return [1.23*10**10,3.1*10**16]

def zbound():
    return [10**(-10),pi-10**(-10)]

def ybound(z):
    return [0,bmax(z)-10**(-10)]

def xbound(z,y,w):
    return [thetal(z,y,w),pi-thetal(z,y,w)]

def f(x,y,z,w):
    return [5.77/10**30*sin(z)*sin(z/2)*y*sin(x)*Heaviside(w-rl(z,y))*Heaviside(w-rd(z,y))/w**2]

result = nquad(f, [xbound, ybound,zbound,wbound])
```

Comment: Not too familiar with Python, but any reason you are passing functions as parameters?

Comment: @charliefox2 That's OK, [`nquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html) can also take callables as bounds so that the inner integral bounds can depend on the outer integration variables.

Comment: Then I would guess the issue is that nquad() expects either wbound() or zbound() to have an argument.

Comment: Also worth noting that `f` should not return a list. The `[`...`]` is superfluous and may even cause an error.

Comment: @kazemakase I did'nt even realize that when I copied the example. The error concerning the bounds is raised before that. To get working code that needs to be changed as well

Comment: @kazemakase oh that's very careless of me. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that error is that although you don't want these bounds to depend on the variables, `nquad` still passes the variables to the functions you provide to it. So the bound functions have to take the right number of variables:

```
def wbound():
    return [1.23*10**10,3.1*10**16]

def zbound(w_foo):
    return [10**(-10),pi-10**(-10)]

def ybound(z, w_foo):
    return [0,bmax(z)-10**(-10)]

def xbound(z,y,w): 
    return [thetal(z,y,w),pi-thetal(z,y,w)]
```

Now the functions `zbound` and `ybound` accept the extra variables but simply ignore them.

I'm not sure about the last bound, `xbound(...)`: Do you want the variables `y` and `z` to be flipped? The supposedly correct ordering according to the definition of [`scipy.integrate.nquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html) would be

```
def xbound(y,z,w):
    ...
```

Edit: As kazemakase pointed out, the function `f` should return a `float` instead of a list so the brackets `[...]` in the return statement should be removed.

Comment: Thx, those are the 2 problems. The variable sequence can be rearranged. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

`nquad` expects a sequence of `bounds`  for its second argument, with a rather stringent syntax.

If the integrand `f` depends on `x, y, z, w` and this is the order of definition, the terms in `bounds` must be, in sequence, `xb`, `yb`, `zb` and `wb`, where each of the bounds can be either a 2-tuple, e.g.,  `xb = (xmin, xmax)`
or a function that returns a 2-tuple.

The critical point is, the arguments of those functions... when we perform the inner integration, in `dx`, we have available `y`, `z` and `w` for computing the bounds in `x`, so that it must be
`def xb(y,z,w): return(..., ...)` — likewise
`def yb(z,w): return (..., ...)` and
`def zb(w): return (..., ...)`.
The bounds with respect to the last variable of integration must be constant.

To summarize

```
# DEFINITIONS

def f(x, y, z, w): return ..  . # x inner integration, ..., w outer integration
def xb(y,z,w): return (...,...) # or simply xb=(...,...) if it's a constant
def yb(z,w): return (...,...)   # or yb=(...,...)
def zb(w): return (...,...)     # or zb=(...,...)
wb = (...,...)

# INTEGRATION

result, _ = nquad(f, [xb, yb, zb, wb])
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation

Comment: May I ask if you have a very strict policy about upvoting?